# How to use Builder in order to create the context

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this method which needed a context so I'm passing it as a parameter.

```
Future<void> myPopup(BuildContext context) {
  return Dialogs.materialDialog(
    context: context,
    ...
  );
}
```

I tried to wrap the whole Dialogs.materialDialog with Builder in order for me not to pass the context anymore but I'm unable to do it.

```
Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Dialogs.materialDialog(
      context: context,
      ...
    );
  },
```

How can I achieve the same output using the Builder?

Comment: Won't work as the return type changes (Future<void>) in first snippet to Widget in second snipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*not to pass the context*, I think you are looking for [`LookupBoundary`](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LookupBoundary-class.html) but currently it is on master-api.

On your case it will be

```
LookupBoundary(
    child: Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Dialogs.materialDialog(
         context: context,
      ...
      )
    );
  },
```

Comment: how did you find that `LookupBoundary`? is there a web page showing new/deleted/updated classes between 2 flutter releases? or was it just a good luck?

Comment: There was a talk some on flutter Community channel, I think simon introduce it live and I was watching it. I didn't find any sort of update-list. But the widget is interesting and kept in my mind from the show, then search on internet[flutter master api] and got it.

Comment: You are welcome, flutter [google group provides release update[(https://groups.google.com/g/flutter-announce)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap your method in a Builder to be able to give it the context. The context can be used from the build method.

```
  Future<void> myPopup(BuildContext context) {
  return Dialogs.materialDialog(
    context: context,
    ...
   );
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { //Context is already defined in the build.
    return TextButton(
      child: Text('Press me'),
      onPressed: () {
        myPopup(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Also @rahul has a point with the method not being assignable to the child widget as the return type is different than what is expected.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to try and learn if it was possible.